# I am tried to implement splash screen for my app as it need to load data into the app from an api

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am working on an app that loads data into app from an api.
I tried to load launchScreen by delaying for 5sec before the app loads. But it is not working.

This is the code I am using, I named the launch screen storyBorad as "splashController" and main storyboard as "initController".

```
var window: UIWindow?

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        self.splashScreen()
        return true
    }

    private func splashScreen() {
        self.window?.rootViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "LaunchScreen", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(identifier: "splashController")
        self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
        print("Timer Started")
        Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 5, target: self, selector: #selector(dismissSplashController), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
    }

    @objc func dismissSplashController(){
        self.window?.rootViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(identifier: "initController")
        self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }
```

can you please look into this?

Comment: It is not a good practice to make a fixed duration of screen display (5 sec). What will happen if in 5 seconds the data in the app does not load from the API? At a minimum, I would recommend implement completion handler for loading of data from API, which will give the information to the launch screen (method `splashScreen`) that the data has completely loaded.

Answer (score 1):

you shouldn't delay the splash Screen on app delegate ,
you can achieve this behavior by design a view the same as splash design in you first view Controller and hide this view in case of succeeding to fetch the data in the main view Controller

Answer (score 0):

You can try to call your api in splashScreen() function and in the completion handler of api call, implement the dismissSplashController(). It will keep your "splashController" screen as root view controller as long as data is being fetched from api and then on receiving required response, it will proceed to "initController".